# MapStruct Is there a way to define defaut enum strategy for unknown value at class level?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm looking to define at mapper class level, a strategy that said if an enum value is not mapped, to map it to null.

Just like i would write at method level:

```
    @ValueMapping( source = MappingConstants.ANY_REMAINING, target = MappingConstants.NULL )
```

So that it applies to all sub mapping method automaticaly generated by mapstruct, without forcing me to declare all of them just to add this line.

Answer (score 4):

Create a 'class' mapper for your enum and then use it in other mapper with the `uses` attribute of the `@Mapper` annotation.

For example :

```
public interface MyEnumMapper {

    @ValueMapping( source = MappingConstants.ANY_REMAINING, target = MappingConstants.NULL )
    public String asString(MyEnum myenum);
}
```

and then to use it

```
@Mapper(uses=MyEnumMapper.class)
public class CarMapper {

    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
}
```

(assuming `Car` object has an attribute of type `MyEnum`)

see the full documentation here : https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a way to not have to declare a method for every enum just to say to map to null if not found. Your answer just make me move the declaration to a sub class.